# Error when saving ObjectContext after replacing Parent item and linking Child item to it

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, foreign-keys, system.data.sqlite

In my application, the interface allows the user to create and delete entities in an Entity Framework model. All changes are added to the `ObjectContext`, and saved only when the user selects "Save".

My question is best asked by means of the following simple example:

I have a Foreign Key relation between two entity types, which I will call `Parent` and `Child` here. The database, in SQLite, is declared as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Parents   (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE Children  
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID INTEGER NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT FK_ChildrenToParents REFERENCES [Parents](ID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

I then build an Entity Framework model on that database, and execute the following actions against it (see code below):

1. Create a `Parent`
2. Save
3. Delete the `Parent`
4. Create a new `Parent` with the same ID number as the original
5. Create a `Child` and provide it with the new `Parent`'s ID number
6. Save (Fails)

```cs
demoDBEntities entities = new demoDBEntities();

Parent originalParent = new Parent { ID = 1 };
entities.Parents.AddObject(originalParent);

entities.SaveChanges(); // First Save

entities.Parents.DeleteObject(originalParent);

Parent newParent = new Parent { ID = 1 };
entities.Parents.AddObject(newParent);
Child newChild = new Child { ID = 2, ParentID = 1 };
entities.Children.AddObject(newChild);

entities.SaveChanges(); // Second Save
```

I get the following error on the second call to `SaveChanges()`:

`"Unable to insert or update an entity because the principal end of the 'demoDBModel.FK_Children_0_0' relationship is deleted."`

It seems the problem is that the Entity Framework links the new `Child` item to the `originalParent` item, which is then deleted and replaced by the `newParent` item. This might sound conceited, but happens quite naturally in my application.

Is there any way for me to work around this problem?

PS: I know it's bad practice to re-use ID numbers of DB entries - however, in my case the ID numbers are Asset numbers, which could theoretically be reused. That said, the above scenario typically happens if the client creates a faulty `Parent`, then deletes it, recreates it, and then creates the `Child` item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the foreign key property `ParentID` you could try to set one of the navigation properties (you must have at least one) and use only one call to `AddObject` to add the complete object graph to the context:

Either:

```cs
//...
entities.Parents.DeleteObject(originalParent);

Child newChild = new Child { ID = 2 };
Parent newParent = new Parent { ID = 1, Children = new List<Child>{ newChild } };
entities.Parents.AddObject(newParent);

entities.SaveChanges();
```

Or:

```cs
//...
entities.Parents.DeleteObject(originalParent);

Parent newParent = new Parent { ID = 1 };
Child newChild = new Child { ID = 2, Parent = newParent };
entities.Children.AddObject(newChild);

entities.SaveChanges();
```